# Issue in passing an argument to a jquery function

Tags: jquery, formbuilder

I'm using [this](https://github.com/botskonet/jquery.formbuilder) jquery plugin to build forms.

In order to allow the modification of a form, I'm trying to load the json for a specified form, previuosly saved on a database.

I have to use

```
<script>
        $(function(){
            $('#my-form-builder').formbuilder({
                'save_url': 'jsp/save.jsp',
                'load_url': 'jsp/load.jsp',
                'useJson' : true 
            });
            $(function() {
                $("#my-form-builder ul").sortable({opacity: 0.6, cursor:'move'});
            });
        });
</script>
```

but I need to have a 'load_url' with a query string, e.g. 'jsp/load.jsp?id=11', where the id is the identifier of the form in the database.

The formbuilder function should be called when user clicks on a 'Modify form' link or when a div loads.

I tried to use:

```
<script>
    $('modify').click(function(){
                var url = 'jsp/load.jsp?id='.$(this).id;
                $("#".$(this).id).formbuilder({
                    'save_url': 'jsp/example-save.jsp',
                    'load_url': url,
                    'useJson' : true 
                });
                $(function() {
                    $("modify ul").sortable({opacity: 0.6, cursor:'move'});
                });
            });
</script>
```

with:

```
<a href="index.jsp?id=${form.id}" id="${form.id}" class="modify">Modify form</a>
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to concatenate your strings using the `+` operator not `.`. So this is `jsp/load.jsp?id=' + $(this).id;` and `$("#" + $(this).id).formbuilder({`

Comment: @Alex: I changed it, but nothing happens. The url = 'jsp/load.jsp?id='+$(this).id; or url = 'jsp/load.jsp?id='+$(this).attr(id); isn't called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript uses `+` to concatenate strings, not `.`.
You'll also need to use `attr()` to grab the `id`.

Change this line: `var url = 'jsp/load.jsp?id='.$(this).id;`

It should be: `var url = 'jsp/load.jsp?id='+$(this).attr('id');`

Comment: +1 this looks like the problem to me. Also, as far as I know using `.` to concatenate strings is PHP syntax, not sure if it's used in other languages too. This gets me every time though, PHP and JS syntax are so similar otherwise.

Comment: @jammypeach: I changed it, but nothing happens. The url = 'jsp/load.jsp?id='+$(this).id; or url = 'jsp/load.jsp?id='+$(this).attr(id); isn't called.

Comment: also this snippet `$("#".$(this).id)`. Anywhere in your code that you've concatenated strings with `.`, use `+` instead. Also, needs `attr()`.